# How to manage the shapekey's position faster?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, shape-keys

In a *Vertex Groups* panel there is a possibility to move the selected group (which lies on the bottom of the list) to the top by clicking the 'down arrow', but in the *Shape Keys* panel there is not such option.
[image]

I've made a model which has over 200 shapekeys. You can modify every part of a body- from the top of the head to the toes.

[image]

The problem is when I try to add a new shapekey to the upper part of the body. It appears on the bottom of the list and I have to click the 'up arrow' over and over again to place it higher. Is there some way to place the new shapekeys on the top faster or add a new shapekey to the specified position on the list?

Answer (score 3):

No, as far as I know, this does not exist in blender without a modification.

**Solution**: Open all of the shape key filtering options and click the (az) symbol; This will alphabetize your list, and since all of your shapes are so organized in the first place, all you have to do is rename a brand new shape to it's proper category and it should end up there automatically.

[image]

This should put all shape keys under their proper headed, as long as the all the headers are like the ones you show above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea Vince, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Could you specify why so we could better provide an answer?

Comment: Your method works, but it organises all the shapekeys alphabetically and I don't want it. I want them to be organised like ones pictured above (uppercased heading showing the name of the body part, and its modification names below).

Comment: Yes, it works that way, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to revive such an old thread but it's the first thing that pops up in Google when I was looking for where else I uploaded my add-on that does exactly this (and more) so I thought to post this here for whoever else is looking for it:
https://blendermarket.com/products/shape-key-manager/docs

I just updated it so that it's compatible with Blender 2.9